# Why is jsfiddle saying the reference is undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm quite new to javascript and jsfiddle. I've been able to toy around with other fiddles that I find, but setting one up myself has proved difficult.

I'm attempting to use a library from npm to get a proof of concept for how it might work. I'm not sure why my import of the module is not working with jsfiddle.

What am I missing to get my fiddle working?

- used the resourced bar to import the unpkg script

```
https://unpkg.com/browse/json-query@2.2.2/index.js
```

- tried using the method outlined in the package readme

```
var json = [...]

jsonQuery('[DisplayText]', json)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I follow the unpkg [link](https://unpkg.com/json-query@2.2.2/index.js) I see that it has `require`s such as:

```js
var State = require('./lib/state')
```

The problem is not only can the browser not understand `require`, it doesn't have files like `./lib/state` available.

I think the problem here is that you are trying to download the raw source, which needs to be built with something like webpack before it can be used in the browser.

Comment: I understand the building w/ webpack idea, but I'm not sure how to make something I build locally available to jsfiddle. Any insight?

Comment: You could either use a CDN service, or perhaps you could bundle up everything into a single file which could be copy/pasted into the jsfiddle